# NetBeans: Javadoc formatting with <code></code> HTML tags

Tags: html, tags, format, javadoc, netbeans-7

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.1.1 and recently discovered how to set the Java formatting schema up to my liking so I can easily format all my classes to a specific standard with a simple keystroke. However, I've found out that in method comments, e.g. Javadoc,

```
<code></code>
```

HTML tags are inserted on their own line. For example:

```
/**
 * Some Javadoc comment. The <code>paramName</code> does blah.
 */
```

Yields this:

```
/**
 * Some Javadoc comment. The
 * <code>paramName</code> does blah.
 */
```

There's plenty of room for the entirety of the text to fit before busting the 80 character limit, yet it still gets a newline. I've explored the Java formatting options and code templates and haven't found anything that fixes this. It's not a huge deal, just an annoyance, as I can use

```
{@code paramName}
```

to the same effect. I just didn't see any examples of this use in Javadoc sourced from the JDK. The Javadoc webpage also doesn't mention it, just the

```
<code></code>
```

tags. As I said, it's not crucial to fix this, but at the same time I want to write standardized Javadoc. Seeing the HTML tags also makes it easier for me to determine where I have such tags.

Comment: It's even worse than that. When you have a <p><pre> tags used </pre></p>, on first format it will put them in a new line and on the next it will separate <pre> into <\n pre> which makes the tag a non-tag and makes the formatting feature useless :/ not sure what to do about that.

Comment: I have found similar issues with other tags, and especially so with nested tags.

Comment: There is a bug submitted in netbeans here https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243706 It is not exactly the same thing, but pretty much yeah - I added a comment, you can add too, to draw more attention from developers.